# iscsi won't start at boot

Tags: linux, iscsi

I am trying to configure iscsi initiator. Everything works accept it won't start at boot. It times out. Once system is up, I am able to manually mount the drive and /etc/init.d/iscsi status says its up. I really don't understand what's going on. Both server and client are KVM on a Centos host. Could someone please help me out?

This is the error from boot.log.
Starting iscsi: iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2015-01.tester1.example.com:target00, portal: 192.168.122.150,3260].
iscsiadm: initiator reported error (8 - connection timed out)
iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals

Comment: Ask [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is iscsi starts before networkManager. I changed the symlink in /etc/rc5.d, so that it starts after NetworkManager.